# Unable to build android in Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm currently stuck with my project.

I use the following:

ionic@2.1.18 (cli)
cordova@6.1.1

I'm developing on a Mac and I've got the android SKDs (v23) installed on my machine.

When I run ionic build android, I get the following exception:

> :processDebugResources
>   /platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3
>   : AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> /platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4
>   : AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:  Execution failed for task
>   ':processDebugResources'. 
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 1

I've already tried removing and re-adding the android platform in ionic. I've also tried installing several android SDK versions.

In my config.xml file I've included the following lines:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23"/> 
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>
```

The java version I'm using is: jdk1.7.0_80.jdk

I'm new to developing with Ionic so I have no idea what else I can try.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a mismatch between the Android compile SDK version and the support library (or the build tools) version.

Try installing the Android SDK version 24 and try again.

Comment: This doesn't help, I've installed both the API and build tools v24. Still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a hint: values-v24 vs build-tools/23.0.3

You are using values for an API level your app does not support.

Comment: Why does it want to use the v24 build tools, since I'm telling it to use API 23?